# Permissions and rôles in an angular 2 app using microsoft Graph

Tags: angular, .net-core, microsoft-graph-api, adal

I am still a newbie and I am creating a CVThèque application with angular 2 and .net core, and I am creating the authentication using Microsoft Graph and adal. The authentication work very well but i don't know how to create the permissions and groups roles to my application knowing that i have 4 different users and every user has a limit access to the application:

- An admin has access to the hole application.
- An employee has the access to only his CV.
- A manager has access to all the CVs in his group and he can modify, add and delete any CVs.
- A commercial can display all CVs but he can not modify or delete or even add a CV.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you need library to manage permissions in your application?

Comment: Hi, Yes exactly .

Comment: You can checkout ngx-permissions library https://github.com/AlexKhymenko/ngx-permissions

Comment: wiki here https://github.com/AlexKhymenko/ngx-permissions/wiki

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll do that.

Answer (score 2):

I also suggest you have a look at the [active-directory-dotnet-webapp-roleclaims](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-roleclaims) sample on GitHub.
It's for ASP.NET (not ASP.NET core), but you will learn how to setup application roles in AAD, and the logic (using Roles in the Authorize attributes) will be the same, as shown here: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-roleclaims/blob/master/WebApp-RoleClaims-DotNet/Controllers/TasksController.cs#L18
```

```
    [Authorize(Roles = "Admin, Observer, Writer, Approver")]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
      ...
    }
```

```

Comment: Including a few quotes and code snippets in the answer would be good :)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback !